# How to prevent ProgressDialog to dismissing on screen rotation change in Android?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have an activity that shows ProgressDialog while connecting to bluetooth device. It works fine until screen orientation changes while ProgressDialog is up. ProgressDialog disappears and when after connection is established, app calls progressDialog.dismiss(); at this point app crashes because there is no ProgressDialog to dismiss. How can i prevent to ProgressDialog dismissing while screen orientation changes?

```
public void prepareViews(int ID, boolean state){
        switch(ID){
        case USERNAME_TEXTBOX:
            LoginUsernameTextBox.setEnabled(state);
            break;
        case PASSWORD_TEXTBOX:
            LoginPasswordTextBox.setEnabled(state);
            break;
        case LOGIN_BUTTON:
            LoginButton.setEnabled(state);
            break;
        case LOGIN_PROGRESSBAR:
            if(state == true){
                LoginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                LoginProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true); }
            else{
                LoginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case CONNECTING_DIALOG:
            if(state == true){
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Connecting", true); }
            else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up to use DialogFragment and it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{



    public void prepareViews(int ID, boolean state){
        switch(ID){
        case USERNAME_TEXTBOX:
            LoginUsernameTextBox.setEnabled(state);
            break;
        case PASSWORD_TEXTBOX:
            LoginPasswordTextBox.setEnabled(state);
            break;
        case LOGIN_BUTTON:
            LoginButton.setEnabled(state);
            break;
        case LOGIN_PROGRESSBAR:
            if(state == true){
                LoginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                LoginProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true); }
            else{
                LoginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case CONNECTING_DIALOG:
            if(state == true){
                showDialog();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

public void showDialog() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        ProgressDialogFragment newFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Dialog");
    }

public static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Connecting to " 
                    + DeviceName.subSequence(0, DeviceName.length() - 17)); 
            return progressDialog;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, to hide it you should call methods on the dialog fragment instead of on the `progressDialog` to keep the implementation of the dialog fragment separate from the activity. I.e. in case you would like to change how the dialog fragment displays info w/o having to change the activity too.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that Android destroys and recreates Activities when you rotate the device. Your problem is likely that `progressDialog` is `null` because after the Activity was recreated that variable was not set again.

You'll need to use a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and keep in mind the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). What you need to do is keep track of whether the dialog was shown and display it again in OnCreate using a DialogFragment.

Previously it was done with [Activity.dismissDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dismissDialog%28int%29) and [Activity.showDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) but those are deprecated now.

More info: [using dialog fragments](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if ( progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
```

here is the link [android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle orientation change yourself to do this.  In your manifest, for all activites you want to do this add android:coinfigChange="orientation".  That will prevent the system from destroying and recreating your app on rotation, and will instead call your activity's onConfigChange function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload `onConfigurationChanged()` and add the `android:coinfigChange="orientation"` to the activity in your manifest.

If you need to handle rotation layout wise you need to do some like the following

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){

    if(!isConnection){    
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }        
}
```

You could also rebuild the progress dialog after you call setContentView() if you would like to handle rotation entirely.